# Google Drive Viewer URLs now give Google Drive Error

Tags: google-drive-api

Starting today I'm getting **"Google Drive has encountered an error"** when users follow the **urls** we present to preview documents stored on Google Drive.  Files are typically Excel and Word.  The same links have worked for months and months.

If I try going to the Google Drive web app select the relevant docs and right click, 
**`"Open With > Google Drive Viewer"`** I get the same error page.

Has something changed/broken?

Comment: I can confirm the problem for PDF files. Our app saves PDFs in Google drive and it's not possible to view them in the Google Drive viewer any more. It seems only files uploaded via the SDK are affected, I can view PDFs that I uploaded manually.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same problem.  Please, can someone from the Google Drive team take a look?Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Go to this page, which is one of Google's official Drive SDK examples that uses the Javascript API to upload a file:
http://googledrive.github.io/cors-upload-sample/


2. Drag a file onto the page and wait for it to upload to your Google Drive account

3. Open https://drive.google.com and find the file you just uploaded.

4. Right click on it and choose "Open with...Google Drive Viewer"

5. Notice the error page that appears

This happens with EVERY file uploaded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: This issue has now been fixed.

This is a bug with the Google Drive Viewer that is affecting all files uploaded through the Drive API. The engineering team has been alerted to the problem.

Comment: What's the chances of a log of the changes being made to Google Drive so that we can see when things are broken and/or fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks Google engineers have resolved the issue with the Google Drive Viewer.  Files I've upload via the Drive SDK are now correctly showing in the Viewer.  Thanks for following up on this, Eric!

Comment: Would be nice to be able to close this with an answer that had come from the Google Engineering team to say they'd fixed it.

Comment: Edited my answer above.