# Google Drive file alternateLink not working for copied files

Tags: google-drive-api

I upload a jpeg file to Drive. I can view it using the alternateLink: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxF4mNYjqljLcnFxMEFhRmxpMEE/edit.

I then copy the file: 'https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.copy?fileId=0BxF4mNYjqljLcnFxMEFhRmxpMEE&_h=5&resource=%257B%250A++%2522title%2522%253A+%2522new+photo%2522%250A%257D&'

When I try to open the copy with the alternateLink: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxF4mNYjqljLajkzU2pZbDFBdkk/edit?usp=drivesdk

I get this error:

```
Google Drive encountered an error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please report the error.

To learn more about Google Drive, please visit our help center.


We're sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help!
- The Google Drive Team
```

I first noticed the problem with files I uploaded programmatically, but the above example was done with the api explorer.

This problem seems to have started in the past couple of days. I was previously able to view the files that my program had copied.

I have made the two documents public.

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as I'm having at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326494/google-drive-viewer-urls-now-give-google-drive-error

Comment: The 'answer' in the duplicate question is not actually an answer, it is a comment on the question. This question describes a different symptom of the same issue, with a different repeatable test.